# Binding jquery autocomplete with json data.Autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Firstly, I am loading data `on document ready` and save it inside a global variable after that I am trying to bind it to autocomplete text box. 
The problem is that i am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

My implemented it as

```
  var jsonData;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function split(val) {
                return val.split(/,\s*/);
            }
            function extractLast(term) {
                return split(term).pop();
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/WebService1.asmx/GetEmailsWithNames",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success:function(data){
                    jsonData = data;
                    CallOnSuccess();
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Some error');
                }
            });
        });
        function CallOnSuccess() {
            $("#<%=txtEmailAddresses.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: jsonData,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=txtEmailAddresses.ClientID%>").val(ui.item.Email);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    return ;
                }
            })
            .autocomplete("instance")._renderitem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
                  .append("<a>" + item.Name + "<br>" + item.Email + "</a>")
                  .appendto(ul);
            };
        }
```

The data i am getting in this way for variable jsonDaTa

```
Object {d: Array[10]}
d: Array[10]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

What's wrong with it? why my autocomplete is not functioning.

Secondly, my requirement is to select multiple values ie show Multiple Emails on the textbox separated by `,`.

How to do this? Help required!!

Comment: First try with data.d, so change jsonData = data.d; in success callback. On which line you get object is not a function?

Comment: sorry to mentioned i have tried this so. i am getting error in binding